# Sending Outlook Email with Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook

I can successfully send an email by OLE between Delphi 10.4 and Outlook 365.

```
try
  Outlook:=GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
except
  Outlook:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
end;

try
  MailItem:= Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem) ;

  SubjectLine:= 'Whatver';
  MailItem.Subject:= SubjectLine;

  EmailTo:= 'somebody@somewhere.com';
  MailItem.Recipients.Add(EmailTo);

  MailItem.BodyFormat := olFormatPlain;
  MailItem.GetInspector;

  Attachment:= 'C:\File.doc';
  MailItem.Attachments.Add(Attachment);

  MessageBodyStr:= 'Dear Friend';
  MailItem.Body:= MessageBodyStr;

  MailItem.Display(False);

finally
  Outlook := Unassigned;
end;
```

This is working just fine.
But I would prefer sending the email directly without displaying the email editor

When I am using this

```
MailItem.Send;
```

I get this

```
EOleSysError: The parameter is incorrect
```

What's wrong ?
How can I skip the editor and just send the email ?
Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use an SMTP client?

Comment: Not really. For my project, I am also collecting incoming emails to process automatically specific attachments.  If details are missing, I need to send an email back to request more information.

Comment: Try     MailItem.SendMail;

Comment: Nop. I get another error.   EOleError: Method 'SendMail' not supported by automation object

Answer (score 4):

Today might be your lucky day, Bob!

I maintain an application that uses the Outlook Object Model to send emails. The code for sending the email has been unchanged for several years, and thousands of users have been using it successfully.

In the last few weeks, some of those users upgraded to the latest versions of Office 365 and started experiencing the exact same "The parameter is incorrect" error when MailItem.Send is called. All of those users had the same things in common:

1. They did **NOT** upgrade our application (they are still running the same version that was working fine for years)
2. They **DID** upgrade Office 365.

Given those two points above, it doesn't take a rocket scientist to conclude that Microsoft must have changed something in the latest versions of Office 365 and that change is causing this error.

I opened a case with Microsoft's Office 365 Support Team, and, as might be expected, the case went around and around circles without Microsoft providing any solution whatsoever.

The stupid thing about the error message "The parameter is incorrect" is that MailItem.Send does not take any parameters!

Anyway, I gave up on Microsoft's Office 365 Support Team and started fiddling with the code, which hasn't been changed in many years.

After much tinkering, I discovered that, for some unknown and undocumented reason, the call to MailItem.GetInspector seems to cause the subsequent call to MailItem.Send to raise the error. When I commented out MailItem.GetInspector, MailItem.Send worked perfectly and did not raise the error.

But for me, commenting out MailItem.GetInspector is not a long-term option because I use the Inspector to do several manipulations of the email body.

So, I read the docs for the Inspector object and found the method Close. I added a call to Inspector.Close after the email body manipulations and before the call to MailItem.Send. Bingo! That fixed the error!!!!

Here is some VBA sample code that works. I tested it in Excel.

```
Sub TestSendEmail()
    Dim app As Outlook.Application
    Dim nameSpace As Outlook.nameSpace
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wordDocumentEditor As Word.Document
    
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Set app = New Outlook.Application
    Set nameSpace = app.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    Set folder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.olFolderOutbox)
    Set mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.olMailItem)
    mailItem.Subject = "Test Subject"
    mailItem.To = "joe.kelly@binarystream.com"
    Set insp = mailItem.GetInspector
    Set wordDocumentEditor = insp.WordEditor
    wordDocumentEditor.Range(0, 0).InsertBefore ("Test Body")
    insp.Close (olSave)
    MsgBox "Calling Send"
    mailItem.Send
    MsgBox "Send Complete"
Done:
    Exit Sub
errorHandler:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Bob, please reply back to let me know if Inspector.Close fixed the error for you.

Comment: Hi FiveLoop. Sorry for the late feedback. I didn't get any notification for your reply. Unfortunately, this is not my lucky day. I still get a different error: Method SendMail not supported by Automation Object. And, as you are an expert, I do have another question. When ready incoming emails, I am using successfully Mail.SenderEmailAddress or  Mail.Sender.Address with Office 365. However, when using with Outlook 2016, I also get an error "not supported by Automation Object". Any advise ?

Comment: @fiveloop, you are the Man! I've been nuts trying to solve this "parameter is incorrect" issue that popped up about 1 month ago in OL365 when calling send(). Thank you!!