# Collecting emails from Outlook Inbox with Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook, firemonkey, ole

I wrote some code to read emails from Outlook Inbox and collect attachments.

This is working just fine. I am using Outlook 2019/Office 365.

I can use both `Mail.SenderEmailAddress` or `Mail.Sender.Address` to get the email address of the sender.

When deploying my application to another computer with Outlook 2016, I get this error:

> EOleError: Method 'Sender' not supported by automation object

Same for `Mail.SenderEmailAddress`

Outlook 2016 or 2019 have the same code stream. See [Outlook versions, build numbers and other trivia](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/200).

Could you help understanding why I get such error on my client's computer and how can I fix that problem?

Are you aware of a free/commercial library or components that could do that smoothly?

This is somehow linked with my other question about [Sending Outlook Email with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213396/sending-outlook-email-with-delphi).

```
try
  Outlook:=GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
except
  Outlook:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
end;

try
  oNameSpace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
  oNameSpace.Logon;

  Inbox:= oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6);
  iNbMail:= Inbox.Items.Count;

  for i:= iNbMail downto 1 do
  begin
    if VarIsNull(Inbox.Items[i]) or VarIsEmpty(Inbox.Items[i])  then
      Continue;

    Mail:= Inbox.Items[i];
    EmailAddress:= Mail.Sender.Address;
    // EmailAddress:= Mail.SenderEmailAddress;
          
    UnReadFlag:= Mail.UnRead;
    iNbAttach := Mail.Attachments.Count;

    for j := iNbAttach downto 1 do
    begin
      Attachment:= Mail.Attachments[j];
      if ExtractFileExt(Attachment.FileName) = '.pdf' then
      begin
        SaveName:= TPath.Combine(InboxFolder, Attachment.FileName);
        Attachment.SaveAsFile(SaveName);
      end;
    end;
    Mail.UnRead:= False;
  end;
finally
  Outlook:= Unassigned;
  oNameSpace:= Unassigned;
  Inbox:= Unassigned;
  Mail:= Unassigned;
end;
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and show working code you use when using Mail.Sender.Address?

Comment: I added the piece of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inbox folder in Outlook is not restricted to contain only mail messages. When iterating through its items you can encounter various item classes like [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem), [`PostItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.postitem), [`MeetingItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem), [`TaskRequestItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskrequestitem) and many others. All of these items support different sets of properties and not all of them have `Sender`, `SenderEmailAddress` or `Attachments` property. If you're interested only in mail items then you need to check item's `Class` property:

```
const
  olMail = $0000002B;

{ ... }

for i := iNbMail downto 1 do
begin
  Mail := Inbox.Items[i];
  if Mail.Class <> olMail then
    Continue;

  { here we can assume we're working with MailItem instance }
  
end;
```

I doubt that Outlook ever returns null or empty item, so the check you do in your code is pointless. If you're interested in other item classes then check out [`OlObjectClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass) enumeration.

I'm not sure why you prefer to use [late-binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding), because Delphi already comes with imported type library `Outlook2010.pas` to automate Outlook in strongly typed manner. The library is located in `OCX\Servers` subfolder of installation folder. In case you need to support pre-2010 Outlook versions you can use unit `OutlookXP` or even `Outlook2000` instead. The code fore iterating mail items using the type library could look like this:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, Winapi.ActiveX, Outlook2010;

function GetOutlookApplication: OutlookApplication;
var
  ActiveObject: IUnknown;
begin
  if Succeeded(GetActiveObject(OutlookApplication, nil, ActiveObject)) then
    Result := ActiveObject as OutlookApplication
  else
    Result := CoOutlookApplication.Create;
end;

procedure ProcessInboxItems;
var
  Outlook: OutlookApplication;
  Inbox: Folder;
  Index: Integer;
  LItems: Items;
  LMailItem: MailItem;
begin
  Outlook := GetOutlookApplication;
  Outlook.Session.Logon(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);

  Inbox := Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
  LItems := Inbox.Items;
  for Index := LItems.Count downto 1 do
  begin
    if Supports(LItems.Item(Index), MailItem, LMailItem) then
    begin
      { do whatever you wish with LMailItem }
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @BobBaudewyns You're welcome! Just out of curiosity - what was the item class that was causing the problem?

Comment: I have changed the code to get other class names for you. I'll install that on Monday. Then, I get back to you.